# Dynamic URL for an image return 404 and onError is not firing

Tags: javascript, image, onerror

I have a dynamic image URL that will return the default image if nothing there is nothing to represent and the response is 404 so my plan to remove the image when onError attribute is fired but the problem the onError is not firing at all, how can fix that?

Comment: `onerror`, not `onError`..

Comment: Where is your code?